# Why is Monkey a monkey?

Tags: names, the-new-legends-of-monkey

The titular character in [*The New Legends of Monkey*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Legends_of_Monkey) is named "Monkey", which is short for his apparently being the "monkey king".

The series is a fantasy/comedy adaptation of the historical Chinese book [*Journey to the West*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West), where the character identified as the ["monkey king", Sun Wukong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_King), is ... well, indeed a *monkey*. In animated and live-action adaptions from China (of which there are plenty), this character is typically depicted as a more or less anthropomorphized monkey.

In the series *The New Legends of Monkey*, in contrast, Monkey appears completely human. There is not the slightest feature about him that would make him resemble a monkey.

**Does he have any kind of backstory in the series that would explain why he is identified as a "monkey" in this adaptation?**

Comment: Sandy is not made of sand, either, nor is Pigsy made of pigs...

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If he were instead named "Steve" then the show would have to be called *The New Legends of Steve* wouldn't it?

Comment: @Valorum: "Sandy" is a common given name. Pigsy is, in the original work, indeed very much a pig (or at least a pig-human-hybrid kind of being).

Comment: @DavidW: Yes, it would. I don't understand the objection.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Apologies, I'm maybe being slow today; I'm not connecting the dots here somehow.  It might help if, ignoring the historical antecedents, you could give some context from the show of Monkey being _identified as_ a monkey, instead of just being named after one.  Similarly, I wouldn't expect the Jade Emperor to actually be made of jade.

Comment: @DavidW - I think it's a fair question. In the latest version, there's no good reason for him to be called the Monkey King. He's not a literal monkey, he isn't the king *of* the monkeys and he displays no characteristics that seem especially monkey-like.

Comment: @Valorum Ah, my overly-literal mind decided that was a different question, and rejected that reading.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  I think the answer to that is that's what he's called in the original, and even if they change the way the character is portrayed, they retained the name to connect the stories.  Just like how modern adaptations of Shakespeare can completely change the setting, but always keep the original character names.  (Like the recent BBC version of Midsummer Night's Dream.)

Comment: @Valorum: Thank you, you outlined that better than anything I came up with at half past midnight.

Comment: @DavidW: I doubt that is comparable. This is not about a mere change in setting. It is about a character name that is less a personal name, and more a *description* of who or what the character is. If anything, comparable cases would be if you could come up with an adaptation of *Batman* where the titular character character keeps calling themselves "Batman" even though any references to bats have been removed. Or a remake of "Planet of Apes", where the entire angle of apes is dropped in favour of regular humans ruling future Earth.

Comment: @O.R. Mapper Since humans are a species of ape, that would still work.

Comment: @Adamant: "Work" in the sense that it is factually correct? Yes. "Work" in the sense of being a fitting title for the movie? Rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [press kit](https://www.transmissionfilms.com.au/uploads/media/Monkey_Press_Kit.pdf) for the TV series indicates that in his natural state, Monkey may be rather more monkeyish than his earthly (human) form would otherwise suggest.

In his younger, pre-imprisonment days, he apparently engaged in *monkey-like behaviour* (one assumes including [flinging poop at passers-by](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0veiTgUQLKw), [stealing mobile phones from tourists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8q1MyVUze8M) and [publicly masturbating](https://tinyurl.com/79b8v7n4)) alongside his monkey brethren, atop his home mountain. This earned him the nickname of 'the Monkey King'.

> Monkey, a young god born from a stone on a mountaintop, lived in plain sight, **enjoying Monkey-ish pursuits with his monkey brethren.** Monkey’s very existence was special and he was earmarked for great things by the gods.
>
> That’s how it used to be… But then everything changed. A battle between the gods and demons, one that was unwittingly set into motion by the young Monkey god. What he did he do? Only Monkey can remember. As punishment the gods locked him in a statue, frozen in time.

Comment: Thank you - I'll accept this answer, as the sourced information provided herein appears to fill in the missing bits that are not mentioned explicitly on the show. (Given that at least the demon names on the show are quite descriptive - think Mothrax, Cranius, Mycelia, etc. - anything less than Monkey somehow *being* a monkey would have really surprised me.)